# Save the data received from an anonymous function in a class object

Tags: javascript, facebook, asynchronous, anonymous-function

I am trying to store the data I receive from a Facebook API call into a class property.

My constructor:

```
function Foo() {
    this.bar = {
        likes: 0
    };
}
```

Method to update the object:

```
Foo.prototype.update = function() {
    FB.api('/me/likes', function (response) { 
        // this.bar['likes'] is out of the scope
    });

}


var foo = new Foo();
foo.update();
```

Is this possible or should I just try to make a synchronous call instead?
I'm not sure if Facebook's API supports it.

Thanks

Comment: You are storing the data in a property of an object, not a class.  JavaScript is a prototypical language and does not have classes like a classical language.  In JavaScript functions are first-class objects, `Foo` is an object.  Capitalizing the first character in the name of a constructor function is just a convention, it doesn't confer any special meaning to `Foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Foo.prototype.update = function()
{
    var self = this;
    FB.api('/me/likes', function (response){ 
        self.bar["likes"] = response;
    });

}
```

If you cache `this` as a local variable then you can reference it inside your callback function.

Alternatively you can use the ES5 bind command or the jQuery alternative [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/). or the underscore alternative [`_.bind`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
FB.api('/me/likes', (function (response){ 
    this.bar["likes"] = response;
}).bind(this));

FB.api('/me/likes', $.proxy(function (response){ 
    this.bar["likes"] = response;
}, this));

FB.api('/me/likes', _.bind(function (response){ 
    this.bar["likes"] = response;
}, this));
```

All of these will make sure that the `this` value in your function is what you expect it to be. (note that `.bind` is ES5 and breaks in old browsers).

If you have jQuery lying around you can use $.proxy. If you don't want to include jQuery, include underscore instead because it's a lot smaller